# Vba vlookup have trouble coding

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Hi I am having trouble working out how to find a way to get data from the lastrow.
I'll try and make some sense of what I am trying to do. My userform collects data then gets sent to my worksheet do some calculations. On a second userform I need to get the calculation back again which will end up in the lastrow but lastrow will always change eg. AB33, AB34, AB35 and so on.

Comment: could you provide us with code?

Comment: I would but I don't have any looking for a starting point.in my Google Search it I thank it should be like =vlookup(worksheet),lastrow,1,1, not sure at this stage cheers Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the lastrow like

```
LastRow = YourWorksheet.Cells(YourWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row //"A" is the column, change it as needed
```

Comment: Thanks for that I will try tomorrow at some stage I have been looking around